# How to store data on phone for a NoSQL database

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using AWS DynamoDB to store user data but would only like the data pushed to the server when the user's phone is connected to wifi.

I know about [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) and [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary), but what's best practice for my common use case: storing data meant for a NoSQL database over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is for you to use a product like AppSync. AppSync will help you model your data using GraphQL backed by AWS DynamoDB. The AppSync SDK enables your app to work both in online and offline modes - the data is synced automatically when the app becomes online - see https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can store them on a JSON file, and afterwards you can use that exact same JSON to upload it to the database.
In case you need more info on how to build a JSON file from your application, take a look at the Wikipedia article on JSON: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON